# Dependabot suggestion to edit yarn.lock results in Rails server refusing to work, saying to run `yarn install --check-files`

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hadoop-yarn, dependabot

I have a Rails application, and Dependabot says:

[image: Dependabot suggestion]

When I modify the yarn.lock file as per that suggestion, and try to run `rails s`, I get this:

```
warning Integrity check: Lock files don't match
error Integrity check failed
error Found 1 errors.

========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================
```

When I run `yarn install --check-files`, my modification is overwritten with the original old offending version.

What should I do?

Comment: I saw this somewhere: `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`